# how to set switch "setOnCheckedChangeListener" in RecycleView card

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Below is a picture of my RecycleView:

[image]

I need to set the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` switch on recycleView card.
I tried to add listener in bindView in adapter 
but the object in adapter is `null`.

adapter class

```
public class CardsSyrFastAdapter extends AbstractItem<CardsSyrFastAdapter, CardsSyrFastAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Card object;

    public CardsSyrFastAdapter(Card object) {
        setObject(object);
    }

    public CardsSyrFastAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return 0;
    }
//The unique ID for this type of item

    //The layout to be used for this type of item
    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.card_list_card;
    }

    //The logic to bind your data to the view
    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder viewHolder, List payloads) {
        //call super so the selection is already handled for you
        super.bindView(viewHolder, payloads);

        //bind our data


        viewHolder.cardName.setText(getObject().getCardName());
        viewHolder.baqaSize.setText(getObject().getCardSize() + "");
        viewHolder.baqaUnit.setText(getObject().getCardUnit());
        viewHolder.default_card_switch.setChecked(getObject().isDefult());

        viewHolder.default_card_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Card card = getObject(); //When the call is null


            }
        });

    }

    public Card getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Card object) {
        this.object = object;
    }


    //The viewHolder used for this item. This viewHolder is always reused by the RecyclerView so scrolling is blazing fast
    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cardName;
        TextView baqaSize;
        TextView baqaUnit;

        Switch default_card_switch;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            cardName = view.findViewById(R.id.CardListName);
            baqaSize = view.findViewById(R.id.baqasize);
            baqaUnit = view.findViewById(R.id.baqaunit);

            default_card_switch = view.findViewById(R.id.default_card_switch);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code where you are getting error

Comment: I edited the question and put the adapter code, the error in onCheckedChanged(), the get object return a null object